# How to keep a child project updated?

Tags: git, svn, version-control

More than four years ago, I created a new independent project based on a existing one. Both were in SVN repos. Child project was customized and both projects evolved independently during next years, but they still have a lot of common code.

Last year, both code repositories migrated to Git. Child project code has less features and has got less developments than new project, so it makes sense to update it with some parts of the parent's code.

So, which would be the way to proceed to keep both projects (partially) synchronized?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have two *divergent* projects. You can't really do what you're trying to do with version control.

Instead, distill the shared pieces out to a *library* stored in a 3rd repo, and then use whatever code-reuse mechanisms your language supports (DLLs, Ruby Gems, Perl modules, whatever) to include the shared bits in each project.

Again, this simply isn't the job for version control, and you're going to have a *very* bad time trying to do this with a version control system.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It seems you are true that VCS are not the tool for the job.

Answer (score 1):

It depends a bit on what kind of project it is. If you would be able to move out common code from both projects into a separate Git repository (just for the common code), you could use [submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules) to integrate that common code back into the specific projects. That way, you only have one (separate) place to work on the common code, and both projects can decide to pull those changes in and build things on top of it.

Another option is to move both projects into a single repository. This would be applicable, if both the projects are very similar (e.g. after updating the child project to match its parent more). So then your child project would be just a separate branch that can pull in changes separately. This would also allow you to pull in changes from the child project to the parent in case that’s useful.

Comment: I like more your second option for my use case. Both projects are still really close, so makes sense have them both in the same repo as different branches.